# Ansible: Restart Processes consuming memory > 75%

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ansible

I am new to Ansible. I have a task to automate infrastructure level 1 using Ansible.

The requirements for the above are:

1. Log in to the server
2. Look for process consuming most memory (greater than specified threshold)
3. Restart offending service .
4. Restart server if above step fails in non business hours (specified) and
   wait for alert to clear or else.
5. Send email to Level 2/ Tier 2 group for further troubleshooting.

**Specific Questions that might help to achieve the said task**

1. How to fetch all processes with memory consumption greater than say 50% and 
   iterate over them in order to restart the service gracefully?
2. How to actually restart the service using the service module for dynamic 
   service names?

I haven't been able to get processes based on memory consumption. All I could achieve was to list processes with most memory consumption. I've used the following command:

> ps -o pid --sort=-%mem | awk 'NR<=2{print $0}' | tail -1

Comment: what do you mean by "infrastructure level 1"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task you want to execute is "restart a service". The problem is identifying the service you want to start. Once that is done, you can trigger a playbook (or even a single ad-hoc execution of the task.

You need a map between process names and services. Your monitoring will raise a set of processes that violate your SLO and trigger your remediation. Let's assume it's an Ansible playbook. You would need a task that looks like:

```
- name: Restart services which consume to much memory
  service:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: restarted
  with_items: bad_services
```

This implies that you've got a variable `bad_services`, which is just a list of service names. You can register some variables to determine whether that task has passed or failed, and deal with the result appropriately. It could be passed as an environment variable:

```
export BAD_SERVICES=$(get_bad_services.sh)
ansible-playbook fix_bad_services.yml -e bad_services=$BAD_SERVICES
```